# MongoDB Find documents which have duplicate propety values

Tags: mongodb

For example we have a collection of polygons, every documents contains property coordinates

```
coordinates: [
  {
    lat: 63.23598239
    lng: 37.94858921
  },
  {...}
]
```

How can we find all documents which have this property duplicated in collection. We need to find 2 or more documents which have the same coordinates array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using aggregation like this :

```
db.test.aggregate([  
   {  
      $group:{  
         _id:"$coordinates",
         sum: {  
            $sum:1
         }, 
         listId: { 
            $push: "$_id"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      $match:{  
         sum:{  
            $gte:2
         }
      }
   }
])
```

it will output all duplicates documents, for example :

```
{ "_id" : [ { "lat" : 63.23598239, "lng" : 37.94858921 } ], "sum" : 4, "listId": [1, 2, 3, 4] }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful, but it doesn't show us Ids of duplicate documents, can we get it somehow ?